# How to configure docker daemon for test enviroment

Tags: docker, testcontainers

I try to setup unit testing agains database with docker. I use library, that runs database image during tests. [Docs](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/docs/usage.md) says:

> Testcontainers will try to connect to a Docker daemon using the
>   following strategies in order:
>
> Environment variables:
>
> ```
> DOCKER_HOST (this should be set to an
> HTTP/HTTPS connection rather than a unix socket at present)
>
> DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
> DOCKER_CERT_PATH
> ```
>
> Defaults:
>
> ```
> DOCKER_HOST=https://localhost:2376
> DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
> DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/.docker
> ```
>
> If Docker Machine is installed, the docker machine environment for the
>   first machine found. Docker Machine needs to be on the PATH for this
>   to succeed.

I have docker installed in Ubuntu 16.04, but dont understund how to configure docker daemon to use with this testing library. Any helps?

Comment: On a standard Ubuntu installation, you normally don't have to configure anything specifically. Do you get any errors? Testcontainers will run a pre-flight checkt, which should give you additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the doc snippet you included:

> (this should be set to an
>   HTTP/HTTPS connection rather than a unix socket at present)

it sounds like this software doesn't support communicating with a Docker daemon over a unix socket, which is the default method the regular `docker` CLI will attempt to connect to docker when `DOCKER_HOST` is unset.

You will need to configure your locally running daemon to listen on a tcp socket in addition to the default /var/run/docker.sock unix socket.

You can set this up manually by generating TLS certificates and putting them in place on both the client and the server. Details on this procedure can be found in the [Protect the Docker daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) article in Docker's official docs.

Comment: Testcontainers contributor here: The doc snippet you've mentioned is out of date, sorry for this. Testcontainers works fine with UNIX sockets nowadays and in general with the default Ubuntu Docker installation.

Comment: @KevinWittek If you want to provide a more accurate answer than what I've got here, I'd be happy to retract this answer that is based on out-of-date information.

Comment: I've already asked for further information in the original question in order to help, happy to help once I know what's the actual error ;)